# Modifying htaccess to redirect page to its mobile equivalent

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following htaccess rules in one of the websites I'm working on:

```
# -------------------
# Custom PHP Settings
# -------------------

php_value include_path ".:/var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/custom/lib:/var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/common/lib:/usr/local/lib/php"

# As long as the lib/ directory is in the include_path, these files will always be found
php_value auto_prepend_file common.header.php
php_value auto_append_file  common.footer.php

php_value upload_max_filesize "50M"
php_value post_max_size       "60M"

# -------------
# Rewrite Rules
# -------------

RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
SetEnv          SITE_ROOT /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs

# special case for home dir (since it's outside of the RewriteBase)
RewriteRule ^/var/www/www.example.com/htdocs$ // [R,L]

# pretty urls for detail pages
RewriteRule ^(.*)/~.+/(.*)/.*$ $1?id=$2 [L]

# webdav
RewriteRule ^webdav(/?.*)$ shared/webdav.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^webdav_file(/?.*)$ shared/webdav_file.php?p=$1 [L]

#images-cache by id
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(id=.*)$
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/content/cache/images/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^.*/?images/display.php content/cache/images/%1 [L]

#images-cache by folder+name
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/content/cache/images/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?images/(.*) content/cache/images/$2 [L]

#style-cache
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/content/cache/style/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?style/(.*) content/cache/style/$2 [L]


#fix pdf index pages
RewriteRule ^(.*)/.pdf$ $1/index.pdf [R,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^.pdf$ index.pdf [R,L,QSA]

#pdf-cache by folder+name
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/content/cache/PDF/$1%1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*).pdf content/cache/PDF/$1%1 [L]

#pdf-cache by folder+name
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/content/cache/PDF/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*).pdf content/cache/PDF/$1 [L]


# If the file is a directory without the trailing slash, add the slash and
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/common/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R,L]

# First look for the specified file in the exact location specified.  (for internal rewrites)
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

# Look for admin logo in config dir before anywhere else
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/config/clientlogo_$1.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^themes/(.*)/images/hdr_clientlogo.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ config/clientlogo_$1.$2 [L]

# look for the specified file in custom and common
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ custom/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/common/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ common/$1 [L]

# look in the non-versioned content dir
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/content/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ content/$1 [L]

# this is for index pages (since the last rule will break auto-index files)
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/$1/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ custom/$1/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/common/$1/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ common/$1/index.php [L]

# index.html
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ custom/$1/index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/common/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ common/$1/index.html [L]


# special case for root index file
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^$ custom/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/common/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^$ common/index.php [L]

# Try stripping off everything but the section (the first directory)
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/$1/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/.*/(.*)$ custom/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/common/$1/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/.*/(.*)$ common/$1/$2 [L]

# If we haven't found it yet, look in the shared directory for the file.
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/shared/$1 -f
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ custom/shared/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/common/shared/$1 -f
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ common/shared/$1 [L]

# Rewrite Image Directory >-------------------------------------------------

# If the file still has not been found, look in the global images/ directory
# (if the path has images/ in it
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/images/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?images/(.*) custom/images/$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/common/images/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?images/(.*) common/images/$2 [L]

# Rewrite rule for image library
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?images/(.*) common/images/display.php?filename=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .pdf
RewriteRule ^(.*).pdf$ common/shared/make.pdf.php [L,QSA]


# Stylesheets in custom/common
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/style/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/style/(.*) custom/style/$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/common/style/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/style/(.*) common/style/$2 [L]

# Dynamic stylesheets >-----------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/style/display.php -f
RewriteRule style/(.*) custom/style/display.php [L]
RewriteRule style/(.*) common/style/display.php [L]

# Javascript in custom/common
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/js/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/js/(.*) custom/js/$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/common/js/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/js/(.*) common/js/$2 [L]

# Rewrite for old URLs and other domains >----------------------------------

# CMS Dynamic pages >-------------------------------------------------------
#mobile
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(.*){2,4}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*ipad.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-|portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android.+mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/mobile/ [R,L,QSA]

# Send everything else to shared/content.php for further processing
RewriteCond %{LA-F:ENV:SITE_ROOT}/custom/shared/content.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ custom/shared/content.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ common/shared/content.php [L]
```

There is a page on my website, let's say: http://example.com/articles/detail/News/my-article which works fine on desktop; however, when viewed on a mobile device, it redirects to mobile homepage. I like that URL to be redirected to its mobile version, which is something similar to http://example.com/mobile/news/news_detail?id=123.

Is there any way I can define this in the above htaccess rules (just for that particular URL) to redirect to the mobile version if viewed on mobile?

Thank you

Comment: It redirects to the homepage because you've told it to do so. If you want to exclude a page then you need to add it as a condition to exclude it and then redirect that specific page by itself using another rule.

Comment: @PanamaJack Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
# set ENV variable for MOBILE agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-|portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android.+mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*ipad [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MOBILE_AGENT:1]

# handle one specific page
RewriteCond %{ENV:MOBILE_AGENT} =1
RewriteRule ^articles/detail/News/my-article/?$ /mobile/news/news_detail?id=123 [L,NC,R=302]

# rest of the URIs
RewriteCond %{ENV:MOBILE_AGENT} =1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/mobile/ [NC]
RewriteRule !\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$ /mobile/ [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I put your exact rules, the link however still redirects to mobile homepage. When I put the middle section by itself, it does work.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/` will stop last rule to execute again. Can you test in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled and see the trace in Network tab.

Comment: In case you have more rules also then post your complete .htaccess in question.

Comment: I edited my question to include the entire htaccess file. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you some repeat lines like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ common/shared/content.php [L]`?

Comment: That's just how this particular CMS is set up, I'm not the original creator of this htaccess file.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working yet. Correct me if I'm wrong please, but when the rules under "handle one specific page" are run and the link is successfully redirected to its mobile version, wouldn't the rules under "rest of the URIs" start acting on it and redirect it to the homepage again? Because that's what's happening right now.

Comment: Problem is that you have tons of rules that even you don't know what they're doing. If you keep my suggested rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line and test them in Chrome dev tool with cache disabled then you can see what's going on in `Network` tab.